# Desigine a NFA but not working

Tags: c, linked-list, nfa

I designed this NFA - where I input a string, and the output is *Accepted* if this NFA accept it else *Not accepted*.

[image]

My code is here -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int accepted = 1;

struct node
{
    char first, second;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *stage, *start, *temp;
    char A[50000], data;
    printf("String: ");
    gets(A);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(A); i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            stage=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            if(A[i] == '0')
            {
                stage->first = 'B';
                stage->second = 'A';
            }
            else if(A[i] == '1')
            {
                stage->first = 'A';
                stage->second = '\0';
            }
            stage->left = '\0';
            start = stage;
            temp = stage;
            stage->right = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            stage=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->right = stage;
            stage->left = temp;
            if(A[i] == '0')
            {
                if(temp->first = 'A')
                {
                    stage->first = 'B';
                    stage->second = 'A';
                }
                else if(temp->first = 'B')
                {
                    stage->first = '\0';
                    stage->second = '\0';
                }
                else if(temp->first = 'C')
                {
                    stage->first = '\0';
                    stage->second = '\0';
                }
                else if(temp->first = '\0')
                {
                    while(1)
                    {
                        stage = stage->left;
                        temp = stage->left;
                        stage->right = '\0';
                        i--;
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            accepted = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(stage->second != '\0')
                        {
                            stage->first = stage->second;
                            stage->second = '\0';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(A[i] == '1')
            {
                if(temp->first = 'A')
                {
                    stage->first = 'A';
                    stage->second = '\0';
                }
                else if(temp->first = 'B')
                {
                    stage->first = 'C';
                    stage->second = '\0';
                }
                else if(temp->first = 'C')
                {
                    stage->first = 'C';
                    stage->second = '\0';
                }
                else if(temp->first = '\0')
                {
                    while(1)
                    {
                        stage = stage->left;
                        temp = stage->left;
                        stage->right = '\0';
                        i--;
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            accepted = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(stage->second != '\0')
                        {
                            stage->first = stage->second;
                            stage->second = '\0';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            temp = stage;
            stage->right = '\0';
        }
    }
    temp = start;
    printf("\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%c => ", temp->first);
        temp = temp->right;
        if(temp->right == '\0')
        {
            data = temp->first;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(accepted && data == 'C') printf("\n\nAccepted.\n");
    else printf("\n\nNot accepted.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to find, what's wrong there.

Comment: Usage of `gets` is deprecated. Use `fgets` or `scanf` instead.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong here? A description of the issues you're having, what output you're expecting with some sample input and the actual output you're getting would be great. Also why weren't you able to debug it?

Comment: To set a pointer to `NULL`, use `NULL` not `'\0'`....

Comment: You have a lot of if with `=` instead of `==`.......... Compile your code with `-Wall` option, You'll find out a lot of things